# Doctrine Many to many not inserting

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Currently, I have two entities `book` and `tag`. I have three tables: `book`, `tag` and `book-vs-tag`

The relationship between `book` and `tag` exists only in `book-vs-tag`, however, is somewhat unidirectional.

table schema for `book`

```
  bookId | bookName | bookISBN
```

table schema for `book-vs-tag`

```
  bookVsTagId | bookId | tagId | entryTimestamp
```

table schema for tag

```
  tagId | tagCode | tagDisplayText
```

My `book` entity contains the following annotation:

```
/**
 * @var tag
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="tag")
 * @JoinTable(name="`book-vs-tag`",
 *     joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="bookId", referencedColumnName="bookId")},
 *    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="tagId", referencedColumnName="tagId")}
 *    )
 */
```

The code to add a `tag` to a `book` is:

```
 /**
 * @param tag $tag
 * @return $this
 */
public function addTag(Tag $tag)
{
    $this->tagList->add($tag);
    return $this;
}
```

Yes, I am initialising the list as `ArrayCollection` on construction. The problem I have is that the entry is not being inserted into `book-vs-tag` and no exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem to work now. Can't remember what I fixed.